# InvalidOperationException: The ViewData item that has the key 'Id' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

when i run the code it gives InvalidOperationException: The ViewData item that has the key 'Id' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'. error what should i do

```
    //Controller
    public IActionResult Create()
    {   
        //ViewBag.Dersler = new SelectList(_db.Dersler.ToList(), "PKfromDersler", "DersName");
        List<SelectListItem>values=(from Ders in _db.Dersler.ToList()
            select new SelectListItem
            {
                Text=Ders.DersName,
                Value=Ders.Id.ToString()
            }).ToList();
        ViewBag.v1 = values;

        
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(Ogretmen obj)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Ogretmenler.Add(obj);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(obj);
    } 





    //view
    <div class="mb-3">
        <h6 >Ders Seçiniz</h6>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(Ders=>Ders.Id,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.v1)
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

`@Html.DropDownListFor(Ders=>Ders.Id,new SelectList(ViewBag.v1,"Value","Text"))`

This is my test result.

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var value = new List<UserModel>
        {
            new UserModel{ id = 1, name = "user1" },
            new UserModel{ id = 3, name = "user3" }
        };
        ViewBag.v1 = value;
        return View();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I noticed you didn't pass the **model** to `View`

Bellow are the following steps

1. First get all the list from `Dersler` table
2. Initialize `ViewBag` by creating `selectlist` and pass the list you generate in first step.
3. Pass model to view.
4. Use `Html.DropDownListFor` to create dropdown using `ViewBag` as `selectlist`

```
public IActionResult Create()
{   
    //ViewBag.Dersler = new SelectList(_db.Dersler.ToList(), "PKfromDersler", "DersName");
    
    var values = (from Ders in _db.Dersler
                  select Ders).ToList();
    ViewBag.v1 = new SelectList(values, "Id", "DersName");
    return View(new Ogretmen()); //Here pass the model object
}
```

`View`

```
@model Ogretmen

<!--
    Your view code...
    ...
    @*
        model.yourId is the id of Ogretmen class for which you bind the value from dropdownlist
    *@
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.yourId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.v1, "-- Option label --", new { @class = "form-control" })
    ...
-->
```

Comment: now i am gettinh this error:
SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Ogretmenler' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
'[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(Ogretmen obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.Ogretmenler.Add(obj);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(obj);
        }'

Comment: @aidasu Check the **posted parameter value** by adding **breakpoint**. then call the `Add` method.

Comment: @aidasu don't pass the value of  `Ogretmenler` while inserting data into the database, because you set the `Identity_Insert` of this table to **Off**